# apply condition to pages created by user roles

Tags: theming, nodes, users

```
if(isset($node) && $node->type == 'page') { 
}
```

In the above code, I need add one more condition, so that it get applied on those pages which was created by users having user role "EDITOR"
 Please help.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(isset($node) && $node->type == 'page') {
  if($node->uid) {
    $node_author = user_load($node->uid);
    if(is_object($node_author)) {
      if(in_array("editor",$node_author->roles)) {
        // This is the condition to match the current node author belongs to editor role.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: downvote with a reason would have helped me either